# Why does this flask code run asynchronously?

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous

I was wondering if I should use asyncio and aiomysql through flask, so I was doing a simple experiment, but there was something I didn't understand.

I understand that flask runs on a single thread and processes it Sequentially. So when processing a request, I understand that if there has IO bound, flask can't process another request, but the result is different from what I think. What's the reason.

```py
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
import asyncio
import aiomysql
import pymysql

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/sync2')
def hihi2():
    print('IO bound start!')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''select Count(*)
    from fruit_defect
    WHERE date between '2022-11-22' and '2022-11-25'
    ''')
    print('IO Bound finish!')
    result = cur.fetchall()
    print(result)
    cur.close()
    return jsonify(result)


@app.route('/sync3')
def hihi3():
    print('CPU BOUND start!')
    c = 0
    for _ in range(1000000):
        c += 1
    print('CPU bound finish!')
    
    return jsonify(1)
```

result img
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOhEi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `@app.route()` [decorator](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) in Flask creates what's called a [hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) (or "event hook"). The decorator indicates that the decorated function is part of `app` even though it appears to be an ordinary function.

When `app.run()` is called, the Flask library uses a synchronous `while` loop to check for new requests constantly. If there is a request for a specific route, the decorator tells Flask to call the corresponding function. Flask *handles these function calls asynchronously*, which is why `app.run()` enables the program to serve multiple people at the same time without the need to create `async` functions.

Comment: Thank you. But I have a tail question. I don't think there's a reason to use aiomysql, asyncio, etc. if it works asynchronous, so under what circumstances should I use it??

Comment: Tools like that are for different libraries and frameworks that don't have the same kind of hidden event loop that Flask does, or for implementing things like that yourself.

Comment: Last question, why is the asynchronous framework fastapi faster if flask also works asynchronously?

Comment: @KIMBucket Im not 100% sure, but I would assume fastapi doesn't have nearly as much overhead as Flask. "Asynchronous" means that the computer can run two functions at the same time to serve two people, but it doesn't describe anything about how long those functions take to return. Flask has a lot of overhead that is created when `app.route()` functions are called.